# Selector Casperjs [CasperError]

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer um teste utilizando [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org).
Quero que ele clique no botão login.

Tenho o seguinte menu:

```
<ul id="menu-top">
<li class="0 first"><a title="" href="/empresa">Empresa</a></li>
<li class="1"><a title="" href="/plano-de-negocio">Plano de Negócio</a></li>
<li class="2"><a title="" href="/produtos">Produtos</a></li>
<li class="3"><a title="" href="/contato">Contato</a></li>
<li class="4 last"><a title="" href="login.php">Área restrita</a></li>
</ul>
```

Para clicar utilizei o seguinte codigo:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});
casper.start('http://localhost/teste');

casper.then(function(){
    this.click('.4.last>a');
});

casper.run();
```

Porém me retorna o seguinte erro:

> [error] [remote] findAll(): invalid selector provided ".4.last>a":Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
>
> CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: .4.last>a

Estou utilizando o firepath para buscar o caminho css do botão (.4.last>a)

Comment: Vai ver ele não gostou que começa com número. Tentou `li.4.last>a`?

Comment: Sim também tentei assim. this.click('li.4.last>a');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema indicando que iria inserir um XPath.
Assim:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.then(function(){
    this.click(x(".//*[@id='menu-top']/li[5]/a"));  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Só para complementar... Uma outra forma simples é utilizar o `clickLabel()`:

`this.clickLabel('Área restrita', 'a');`

ou ainda, ajustar o CSS Path para:

`'#menu-top > li:nth-child(5) > a'`

ou ainda uma terceira possibilidade:

```
'a[href="login.php"]'
```